# Returning null when trying to read a column from database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Whenever i am trying to read Answer it it always returning null , while all the parameter are filled correctly . Database table are also filled correctly so why it's returning null.

```
    public MidSemAnswers getAnswer(String marksId,int answerID, String subject)
{
    openReadable();
    String select_query= "SELECT * FROM " +MID_SEM_ANSWERS_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_MARKS_ID + " = " + marksId +" AND " + KEY_ANSWER_ID + " = " + answerID +" AND " + KEY_SUBJECT + " = '" + subject + "'" ;
    Log.d(LOG, select_query);
    Cursor c= m_sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(select_query,null);
    MidSemAnswers midSemAnswers=new MidSemAnswers();

    if( c != null && c.moveToFirst())
    {
        midSemAnswers.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
        midSemAnswers.setSubject(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUBJECT)));
        midSemAnswers.setAnswer_id(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER_ID)));
        midSemAnswers.setAnswer(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER)));
    }
    c.close();
    return midSemAnswers;
}
```

Here it is whole database code :

```
   public class CDataSource
               {
private static final String LOG= "DatabaseHelper";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "questionWizardBank";
//table_names
private static final String MID_SEM_QUESTION_TABLE = "midSemQuesBank";
private static final String MID_SEM_ANSWERS_TABLE = "midSemAnsBank";

//Common column name
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_SEM_ID = "sem_id";
private static final String KEY_SUB_ID = "sub_id";
private static final String KEY_MARKS_ID = "marks_id";
private static final String KEY_SUBJECT = "subject";

//questions table common column name
private static final String KEY_QUESTION_ID = "question_id";
private static final String KEY_QUESTION = "question";
//answers table common column name
private static final String KEY_ANSWER_ID = "answer_id";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer";



private static CDataSource m_oInstance;
private static final Object m_oInstanceMonitor;

/**
 * It is a static class initializer.
 */
static{
    m_oInstanceMonitor=CDataSource.class;
}

private final Context m_context;
private DatabaseHelper m_DatabaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase m_sqLiteDatabase;



//table creation statements
//mid sem question table creation statement
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MID_SEM_QUESTIONS= "CREATE TABLE "
        + MID_SEM_QUESTION_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ KEY_SEM_ID + " INTEGER,"
        + KEY_SUB_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_MARKS_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_SUBJECT + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_QUESTION_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT"+")";

//Mid sem answers table creation
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MID_SEM_ANSWERS="CREATE TABLE "
        + MID_SEM_ANSWERS_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_SEM_ID + " INTEGER,"
        + KEY_SUB_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_MARKS_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_SUBJECT + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_ANSWER_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT"+")";
/**
 * Constructor .
 * @param context  Respective UI context.
 */

public CDataSource(Context context)
{
    this.m_context = context;
}
/**
 * The following function checks weather the class is initiated or not,
 * if not it creates an instance of the current class.
 *
 * @param    context    Respective UI context
 * @return   instance of CProfileDataSource
 */

public static CDataSource getInstance(Context context){
    synchronized(m_oInstanceMonitor) {
        if(m_oInstance ==null){
            m_oInstance=new CDataSource(context);
            return m_oInstance;
        }
    }

    return m_oInstance;
}

/**
 * The following method determines if the class is initiated then make it's instance null or release the instance.
 */
public static CDataSource releaseInstance(Context context){
    synchronized(m_oInstanceMonitor)
    {
        if (m_oInstance != null)
        {
            m_oInstance = null;
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Open database for insert ,update ,delete or any kind of writable operations.
 * @throws SQLException  An exception that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing or execution.
 */
private synchronized void openWritable() throws SQLException
{
    m_DatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(m_context);
    m_sqLiteDatabase = m_DatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

/**
 * Open database for any kind of readable operations.
 * @throws SQLException  An exception that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing or execution.
 */

private synchronized SQLiteDatabase openReadable() throws SQLException
{
    m_DatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(m_context);
    m_sqLiteDatabase = m_DatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return m_sqLiteDatabase;
}
//add mid sem questions to MID_SEM_QUESTION_TABLE

public void addMidSemQuestions(MidSemQuestions midSemQuestions)
{
    openWritable();
    m_sqLiteDatabase.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_MARKS_ID, midSemQuestions.getMarks_id());
        values.put(KEY_SUBJECT, midSemQuestions.getSubject());
        values.put(KEY_QUESTION_ID, midSemQuestions.getQuestion_id());
        values.put(KEY_QUESTION, midSemQuestions.getQuestion());
        // Notice how we haven't specified the primary key. SQLite auto increments the primary key column.
        m_sqLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(MID_SEM_QUESTION_TABLE, null, values);
        m_sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
       // Log.d(LOG,"Database: "+values);

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(LOG,"Error while trying to add mid sem questions to database");
    }finally {
        m_sqLiteDatabase.endTransaction();
    }
}

//add mid sem answers to MID_SEM_ANSWERS_TABLE

public void addAnswers(MidSemAnswers midSemAnswers)
{
    openWritable();
    m_sqLiteDatabase.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_MARKS_ID, midSemAnswers.getMarks_id());
        values.put(KEY_SUBJECT, midSemAnswers.getSubject());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER_ID, midSemAnswers.getAnswer_id());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, midSemAnswers.getAnswer());
        // Notice how we haven't specified the primary key. SQLite auto increments the primary key column.
        m_sqLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(MID_SEM_ANSWERS_TABLE, null, values);
        m_sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        Log.d(LOG,"Database: "+values);

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(LOG,"Error while trying to add mid sem answers to database");
    }finally {
        m_sqLiteDatabase.endTransaction();
    }
}
public List<MidSemQuestions> getQuestionsList(String marks_id, String subject)
{
    openReadable();
    List<MidSemQuestions> midSemQuestionsList=new ArrayList<MidSemQuestions>();
    Cursor cursor = m_sqLiteDatabase.query(MID_SEM_QUESTION_TABLE,
            new String [] {KEY_MARKS_ID, KEY_QUESTION_ID, KEY_SUBJECT, KEY_QUESTION },
            KEY_MARKS_ID +"=?" +" AND " + KEY_SUBJECT +"=?",
            new String[] {marks_id, subject },
            null, null, null);
    Log.d(LOG,""+cursor);
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            MidSemQuestions midSemQuestions=new MidSemQuestions();
            midSemQuestions.setQuestion_id(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUESTION_ID)));
            midSemQuestions.setQuestion(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUESTION)));
            Log.d(LOG,"inside cursor"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUESTION)));
            //adding to mid sem question list
            midSemQuestionsList.add(midSemQuestions);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }
    Log.d(LOG,""+midSemQuestionsList);
    return midSemQuestionsList;
}
//get single mid sem answer
public MidSemAnswers getMidSemSingleAnswer(long mid_sem_ans_id)
{
    openReadable();
    String select_query= "SELECT * FROM " +MID_SEM_ANSWERS_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = " + mid_sem_ans_id;
    Log.d(LOG, select_query);
    Cursor c= m_sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(select_query,null);
    if(c!=null)
        c.moveToFirst();
    MidSemAnswers midSemAnswers=new MidSemAnswers();
    midSemAnswers.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
    midSemAnswers.setSubject(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUBJECT)));
    midSemAnswers.setAnswer_id(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER_ID)));
    midSemAnswers.setAnswer(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER)));
    return midSemAnswers;
}
public MidSemAnswers getAnswer(int answerID, String subject)
{
    openReadable();
    String select_query= "SELECT * FROM " +MID_SEM_ANSWERS_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_ANSWER_ID + " = " + answerID +" AND " + KEY_SUBJECT + " = '" + subject + "'" ;
    Log.d(LOG, select_query);
    Cursor c= m_sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(select_query,null);
    MidSemAnswers midSemAnswers=new MidSemAnswers();

    if( c != null && c.moveToFirst())
    {
        midSemAnswers.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
        midSemAnswers.setSubject(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUBJECT)));
        midSemAnswers.setAnswer_id(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER_ID)));
        midSemAnswers.setAnswer(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER)));
    }
    c.close();
    return midSemAnswers;
}

public MidSemAnswers getAnswer(String marksId,int answerID, String subject)
{
    openReadable();
    String select_query= "SELECT * FROM " +MID_SEM_ANSWERS_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_MARKS_ID + " = '" + marksId +"' AND " + KEY_ANSWER_ID + " = '" + answerID +"' AND " + KEY_SUBJECT + " = '" + subject + "'" ;

  //  String select_query= "SELECT * FROM " +MID_SEM_ANSWERS_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_MARKS_ID + " = " + marksId +" AND " + KEY_ANSWER_ID + " = " + answerID +" AND " + KEY_SUBJECT + " = '" + subject + "'" ;
    Log.d(LOG, select_query);
    Cursor c= m_sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(select_query,null);
    MidSemAnswers midSemAnswers=new MidSemAnswers();

    if( c != null && c.moveToFirst())
    {
        midSemAnswers.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
        midSemAnswers.setSubject(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUBJECT)));
        midSemAnswers.setAnswer_id(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER_ID)));
        midSemAnswers.setAnswer(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER)));
    }
    c.close();
    return midSemAnswers;
}


/**
 * getting midsem question count
 */
public int getMidSemQuestionCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + MID_SEM_QUESTION_TABLE;
    openReadable();
    Cursor cursor = m_sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return count;
}
// closing database
public void closeDB() {
    openReadable();
    if (m_sqLiteDatabase != null && m_sqLiteDatabase.isOpen())
        m_sqLiteDatabase.close();
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MID_SEM_QUESTIONS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MID_SEM_ANSWERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + CREATE_TABLE_MID_SEM_QUESTIONS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + CREATE_TABLE_MID_SEM_ANSWERS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: show, what you get in logs of the query: `Log.d(LOG, select_query);`. Your query may be incorrect.

Comment: @VladMatvienko  SELECT * FROM midSemAnsBank WHERE marks_id = '2' AND answer_id = '1' AND subject = 'C'